# Debugging PHP Project using XDebug with Netbeans Crashes

Tags: php, linux, netbeans, xdebug, netbeans-8

I have xdebug (2.6.0) installed on my machine (GNU/Linux Ubuntu 16.04) to debug PHP 7 project running with XAMPP apache 7.2.3, developing on Netbeans 8.2.

Everything is working fine. I opened another project (using the same configurations), added a breakpoint and started debugging the project to fix a bug. As soon the debugger reaches the breakpoint, I can see from glances (a system monitor tool) the memory usage is increasing insanely until it almost reaches 100% and then starts using swap space. That's when the system gets really really slow and I couldn't use it any more. I have to restart the machine to get it back working.

This is a very strange behavior to me and I cannot even guess what to look at or the key words to research with.

I did the usual trials:

- Restarting netbeans, XAMPP, and the machine.
- Changing the breakpoint
- Switching to the previous project and validating that this happens only with the other project in particular.

I googled with keywords like: netbeans - memory blow - system crash - xdebug - breakpoint - PHP - high memory usage

You might find the following snippet off php.ini interesting:

```
zend_extension = /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by clearing/deleting all files and directories at `~/.netbeans` (I'm using Netbeans on Linux Ubuntu).

Removing the cache didn't solve the problem. Deleting netbeans project files didn't solve the problem.